# Sorting array by priority found in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays, the first one has the priorities that will sort the other array based on its value here is an example :

The defined priority array is:

$priorities = [ 4 => 1, 3 => 2, 2 => 3, 1 => 4 ];

The keys in this array is the order of the value in the array, this means that for the first value 1 it's order number is 4 and so on,

The second array is values array as follow:

$values = [1,4];

I just need the value of the first order in the values array,
so the expected output is :

[
4
]

another example and expected result:

$priorities = [ 4 => 2, 3 => 1, 2 => 3, 1 => 4 ];

$values = [2,1];

Expected output is:
[
2
]

Comment: I didn't got the logic to get Expected output.would you please explain it in detail. Thanks

Comment: thanks for you response but i found the solution .